# How to sort results of directory search...?

Tags: php, sorting, search, directory

I have a sub directory called "logs" where I store files for download. I'm trying to create a dynamic download page.

There are 5 raids that are referenced (dragonsoul, firelands, tier11, tier14 and ulduar) and the files in the log folder and named by the format ex. dragonsoul07072013.csv (where the end of the name is a date).

The download page:

I have a form with a select list for each of the raids that submits to itself.

```
<?php
$raidref=$_POST['raid'];

function getfilename($filedate)
    {
        return $filedate[1];
    }

$path = realpath('logs');

foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $file)
    {  
        if (isset($raidref) and $raidref!="")
            {
                $filedate=explode($raidref,$file);
                $filedatestr=getfilename($filedate);
                $filename=$raidref.$filedatestr;

                if ($filedatestr=="")
                    {unset($filename);}  

                if (isset($filename))
                    { echo"$filename<br /><br /><input type=\"button\" value=\"Download\" onClick=\"download('../logs/".$filename."')\"><br /><br />";}
            }    
    }
```

This code works as is but I want to be able to sort the files found so that the most recent file is on top.

The way the code works now is you select a raid from the drop down, submit and it will display the name of the file and a download button and it will repeat these for each file found that includes the name of the raid in the file.

Seeing as the file name includes dates in it, it'd be easier for people to get to the right download if the most recent link is at the top.

How should I go about printing my results sorted descending?

**How it currently displays:**

dragonsoul07072013.csv
Download

dragonsoul07142013.csv
Download

dragonsoul07212013.csv
Download

**How I'd like it to display:**

dragonsoul07212013.csv
Download

dragonsoul07142013.csv
Download

dragonsoul07072013.csv
Download

Also as a note, please explain your answers. I'm learning php from trial and error and research as I need to do things so your explanations will help a lot so I can figure this out on my own in the future (I actually hate to ask for help but I just don't have a clue of how to even approach this).

---

Seeing as I'm new to the website, I can't answer my own question for another 8 hours but I just wanted to let you guys know your answers helped. This is my revised code, which seems to be doing the trick!

```
<?php
$raidref=$_POST['raid'];
function getfilename($filedate) {return $filedate[1];}

$files=array();

$path = realpath('logs');
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)) as $file)
{

if (isset($raidref) and $raidref!="")
    {
        $filedate=explode($raidref,$file);
        $filedatestr=getfilename($filedate);
        $filename=$raidref.$filedatestr;
        if ($filedatestr=="") {unset($filename);}

        if (isset($filename)) {$files[]=$filename;}
    }

}

arsort($files);

foreach ($files as $files)
{
    echo"$files<br /><br /><input type=\"button\" value=\"Download\" onClick=\"download('../logs/".$files."')\"><br /><br />";
}    
?>
```

Comment: keep the file name into an array and sort it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the files into an array.

Use the sort() function.

Loop through array.